# service reference wont update when I add a radtreeView?

Tags: asp.net, web-services, telerik

I have a web service project that is referenced by another project. In the web service I have a function that I want to use to populate a telerik radTreeView. The webService builds successfully but if I try to update/add the web service to my main project I get this error:

```
Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved: 'http://localhost:49304/Service1.asmx'. 
There was an error downloading 'http://localhost:49304/Service1.asmx/_vti_bin/ListData.svc/$metadata'.
```

### The request failed with the error message:

Request format is unrecognized for URL unexpectedly ending in '/_vti_bin/ListData.svc/$metadata'.

This is a simplified version of the web service class I'm writing:

```
  namespace MCMwebservice
{`  
[WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
[System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]


 [ScriptService]
public class Service1 : System.Web.Services.WebService
{
  [WebMethod]
    public bool getBool(RadTreeView TreeSites, string Demogs) {  //dummy method for now
        return true;
    }
}
```

If I remove the telerik radtreeview parameter then it will update, so I know that's the issue. The main project has the telerik.web.ui and skins dll. Is there a certain reference or tag I need to add to my main project or in my web.config? Please Help!

thanks

Will

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the WCF doesn't know how to serialize your telerik control, so either pass to WCF some simple type variable or create own serializer for it.

You should create own tree class that you can pass between WCF service and client as Data Contract in WCf and then expose it to client,

Also you can't just create the same class both in client and service side. WCF creates it's own proxy when you reference it and therefore it needs to be declares as DataContract in WCF.

That's how you do it usually:

```
[DataContract]
public class YouTelerikData
{
    // Apply the DataMemberAttribute to the property.
    [DataMember]
    public string SomeData {get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public int SomeInt {get; set;}
}
```

and then you pass above class to your WCF service, which will serialize correctly

```
[OperationContract]
bool SendData(YourTelerikData someData);
```

however, it will be hard as I assume you need to pass some tree (as the control name suggests).

I have found solution to that problem here:

[Passing recursive collection through WCF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3625504/passing-recursive-collection-through-wcf)

Comment: What do you mean? Where I am creatin the same class?

Comment: Now when I read your post I realize that you may not be talking about WCF services, if you have old asmx web service then only manual binary/xml serialization is an option for you.

Comment: Actually I had just changed it to wcf. giving it a shot now.

Comment: So,my boss gave me some code to do the JSON/xml, method and it seems to work!